# how to? move to a postion

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hello all

I have successfully implement the move_base package onto the gazebo. My goal is to move the robot to a specify position in x,y,z coordinate without too much worrying about avoiding the ostacles. Any ideas in which package I could use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3206/how-to?-move-to-a-postion/) by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mrit91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/400/mrit91/) on 2013-07-02**:
You could either give a command through the terminal using rosservice call /gazebo setmodelstate pose, or you could write a code using this service and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What do you mean by "successfully implement the `move_base` package onto the gazebo"?

If you are using ROS, you can create a map of the environment for navigation purposes.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0